# How to make authorization in android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making android app. I want to make authorization system in the form of "login and password" window. I had an idea to write edittext value to string, then send this strings to server. When server accepts this data, it should send back the confirmation of data validity and the next activity should be opened.
How to do that?

There is my activity code:

```java
package com.bk.cryptit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton;
import android.widget.*;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final EditText haslo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Button button_zaloguj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        String login_content = login.getText().toString();
        String haslo_content = haslo.getText().toString();
        int login_content_length = login_content.length();
        int haslo_content_length = haslo_content.length();
        boolean button_status = false;
        button_zaloguj.setEnabled(button_status);

        if (login_content_length==0 || haslo_content_length==0) {

        } else if (login_content_length>0 || haslo_content_length==0) {

        } else if (login_content_length==0 || haslo_content_length>0) {

        } else if (login_content_length>0 || haslo_content_length>0) {
            button_status = !button_status;
        }

        button_zaloguj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nextauthorizationinformation = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NextAuthorizationInformationActivity.class);
                startActivity(nextauthorizationinformation);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, apply app side validations. If you have email & password field, make sure you check for the empty string by using TextUtils.isEmpty, check for email address validation. Now when it comes to the password field, again check for empty string. Then, make sure you give your input type as password, apply this property from xml itself. After all these validations, give a call to your web service. 
For instance, if you are using retrofit library for web service implementation, it has Success callback method, so in this method give the call to your next activity. 
If it comes to failure method, show some error toast.

Comment: Can I use service to this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Firebase.

Firebase provides many free services and one of them is 
**Firebase Auth** which is apparently what you need.

*Firebase Auth* is a service that can authenticate users using only client-side code. It supports social login providers Facebook, GitHub, Twitter, and Google. Additionally, it includes a user management system whereby developers can enable user authentication with email and password login stored with Firebase.It is secure too and you don't have to worry about the security.

Documentation for Firebase Auth -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

Udacity provides a free course on Firebase too.